# How to delete pictures from iCloud but keep on iPhone?

Tags: icloud, photos

I would like to quit using iCloud Photos, therefore I would like to delete my pictures from iCloud but keep everything on my phone.
When I try to turn off iCloud photos it wants to delete photos from my phone.

Is there a clean way to stop using using iCloud photos but keep photos on my phone?

Comment: Set the phone to "keep originals", let it download everything, then turn iCloud Photo Library off.  It wants to delete things because the pics aren't on the device.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful. When I do that the photos are not deleted from icloud.

Comment: Good.  They weren't supposed to be.  If you want them deleted from iCloud, then delete them from iCloud.  Make doubly sure you have everything you want before you do.

Comment: Yeah I agree. My question is: How to delete pictures from iCloud but keep them on iPhone? I think you told the -how to keep on iPhone- part. Do you also know how to delete them from iCloud? Apple's description on how to [Delete photos in iCloud Photos](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204247) will also delete them from the device.

Comment: iCloud Photo Library is a sync service.  The only way to have them not match is to not use it.

Comment: Well, thats the goal. iCloud Photos is already deactivated on the iPhone, now I want to delete the photos on iCloud.